# Actual PostGIS query execution time MUCH slower than expected

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, performance, spatial-index

I've run into a performance problem from which I'm not sure how to move forward. I have a table with ~150M rows. And I have a query that in `EXPLAIN` has a cost of just `cost=0.55..209.36`, but in `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` the actual time is `time=221.710..3538323.420` (it takes almost an hour to run!).

The table is more or less:

```
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id         | bytea                       |           | not null |
 some_id    | bytea                       |           | not null |
 other_id   | bytea                       |           | not null |
 geometry   | geometry                    |           | not null |
 deleted_at | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 ...other columns
Indexes:
    "model_id" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "model_some_id_paging" btree (some_id, id DESC) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
    "model_other_id" btree (other_id) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
    "model_geometry" gist (geometry) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
    ...other indexes
Check constraints:
    "model_valid_geometry" CHECK (st_isvalid(geometry))
Referenced by:
    ...references by one other table
```

And the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM model
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
  AND ST_Intersects(geometry, $1)
  AND other_id IN ($2) -- single value, so equivalent to other_id = $2
  AND some_id = $3;
```

As expected, the query planner uses the partial index on `geometry`, results of `EXPLAIN`:

```
 Index Scan using model_geometry on model  (cost=0.55..209.36 rows=15 width=424)
   Index Cond: (geometry && '0103000020E61000000100000005000000883E0E6F224A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340883E0E60044A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340883E0E60044A5EC0BC5459C0ADA64340883E0E6F224A5EC0BC5459C0ADA64340883E0E6F224A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340'::geometry)
   Filter: ((other_id = '...'::bytea) AND (some_id = '...'::bytea) AND _st_intersects(geometry, '0103000020E61000000100000005000000883E0E6F224A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340883E0E60044A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340883E0E60044A5EC0BC5459C0ADA64340883E0E6F224A5EC0BC5459C0ADA64340883E0E6F224A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340'::geometry))
```

(the geometry is not very large)

And the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (which takes almost an hour to execute):

```
 Index Scan using model_geometry on model  (cost=0.55..209.36 rows=15 width=424) (actual time=221.710..3538323.420 rows=290 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (geometry && '0103000020E61000000100000005000000883E0E6F224A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340883E0E60044A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340883E0E60044A5EC0BC5459C0ADA64340883E0E6F224A5EC0BC5459C0ADA64340883E0E6F224A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340'::geometry)
   Filter: ((other_id = '...'::bytea) AND (some_id = '...'::bytea) AND _st_intersects(geometry, '0103000020E61000000100000005000000883E0E6F224A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340883E0E60044A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340883E0E60044A5EC0BC5459C0ADA64340883E0E6F224A5EC0BC5459C0ADA64340883E0E6F224A5EC058ACBD2F91A64340'::geometry))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 12
 Planning Time: 0.297 ms
 Execution Time: 3538324.292 ms
```

The geometries stored in the `model` table are all small. ~61% are points, ~37% polygons, ~2% line strings, and the rest are multipolygons. The `model` table itself is 119 GB and the `model_geometry` index is 43 GB. I'm using AWS Aurora compatible with Postgres 11.12 and PostGIS 2.4.4.

AWS Performance insights shows that this query spends time mostly on `IO:DataFileRead`, which is:

> A session is reading data from Aurora storage. This may be a typical wait event for I/O intensive workloads. SQL statements showing a comparatively large proportion of this wait event compared to other SQL statements may be using an inefficient query plan that requires reading large amounts of data.

Other things to note: rows with `deleted_at IS NULL` constitute over 99% of all the rows, and out of those almost 96.5% of rows have the requested `some_id` and `other_id`. I.e. the most selective condition is the one on `geometry`.

I have run `vacuum verbose analyze model`, but it didn't do much. I'm planning to cluster the table on geohashes of the `geometry` table (https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/clusterindex.html#clustering-on-geohash), but I'm not sure what else to do.

Edit: The geometries are not line strings. They are mostly points and polygons. Updated the description above with more details about the geometry types.

Comment: If *"`deleted_at IS NULL` constitute over 99% of all the rows"* (i.e. 99% of al rows *are* `NULL`), the purpose of a partial index is literally being defeated. The massive I/O is likely triggered by a lack of available system memory (physically and/or by means of settings, e.g. *work_mem* and *shared_buffers*) and thus large temporary tables to be stored on disk during execution. Clustering can definitely help with I/O *overhead* due to page access randomness, but I'd say most significantly here is the available system memory to effectively cache relations.

Comment: A safe way to mitigate this can be table partitioning, if you can find a (set of) attribute(s) that you can use to partition your data with minor skew (similar sized partitions), and with which you can statically (vs dynamically, e.g. based on a lookup attribute - PG 11 has only limited capabilities here) limit partition access in queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was actually surprised that 99% of rows had `deleted_at IS NULL`. It used to be less in the past, and we'll eventually get rid of this column anyway, and use non-partial indexes. We can try tweaking the available memory.

Comment: I need to read up on partitioning, but is it possible to partition on a geometry somehow? Also, can partitioned tables be clustered? And lastly, do newer versions of Postgres/PostGIS have something more to offer here? We'll be upgrading soon-ish.

Comment: You may be able to cluster each child table individually, but you can also insert by order. The actual benefit from partitioning is that the relations (including indexes) are broken down into smaller chunks, getting accessed only if needed (based on the partition key), which in turn may allow to load the full relation into memory. There has been a constant improvement on declarative partitioning over the course of PG versions > 10. You can partition by regular spatial distribution patterns (regular grid, geohash, etc.), but it may be more efficient to use a simple attribute.

Comment: Our `work_mem` is 4 MB, other parameters are quite high (`shared_buffers` is ~20 GB (the machine has 32 GB of memory). I tried `set work_mem='128MB'` and then run `explain analyze` on the query, but the execution time was the same as before (almost 1 hour). Unless I'm missing some crucial DB parameter, the problem might lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have clustered the column on the geohash of the geometry, and it has brought the execution down to milliseconds! I used the technique referenced in my question: https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/clusterindex.html#clustering-on-geohash (So far I have tried it on an exact replica of the database, not the live system, but that shouldn't affect anything.)

Edit: what I have done eventually is that I run:

```sql
ALTER TABLE model CLUSTER ON model_geometry_geohash;
```

And then run [pg_repack](https://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/) on it. It solved the problem in less time than `CLUSTER`, and without locking the whole table.